# Amazon S3 Billing like requester pays but for storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there an AWS feature to send the bill for an Amazon S3 bucket to another AWS account? I have seen the requester pays however I'm only interested in the storage fees.

We are building an archiving application that will copy data from a central source to an Amazon S3 bucket. The archiver app will be run in the same aws account that the central app is in. Each team has there own AWS account. We are attempting to use cross account S3 access however its adding a significant amount of complexity to our archiver app. Is there a way we could create multiple s3 buckets inside our main account and have the storage bill sent to other AWS accounts?

Comment: To be clear: Your goal is to allocated storage costs for objects stored in S3 to the respective teams?

Comment: Thats correct. I would like to bill a team for there aws s3 storage that exists in our account.

Comment: What problems are you having authenticating your archiver app with a cross-account IAM role (allowing it to archive directly to destination S3 buckets owned, and paid for, by the target AWS accounts)?

Comment: You should figure out your issues with cross-account S3 access and let each team provide S3 buckets from their own accounts. Feel free to post another Question to obtain assistance. (Hint: It would just need a Bucket Policy on the buckets that each team wants to share with your central app.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned, I would assume that you did not try the `AWS Organization` service yet. It helps you get a consolidated billing for all the accounts under one main account.

Each of your teams can have their own accounts, and by opting for AWS Organization, you would bring all of these under one umbrella account and pay the consolidated bill.

Comment: Consolidated Billing is no silver bullet for cost allocation to the teams, which I believe OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no automatic functionality to send the bill to the respective teams.**

What you could do is create separate S3 buckets for each team and use cost allocation tags on the buckets. This should allow you to figure out which teams caused what storage costs based on the bill. You can create a reporting process based on that and get the teams to pay their share of the bill.

More on that can be found in the official docs: [Using cost allocation S3 bucket tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CostAllocTagging.html)